# How to work with a custom membership provider in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am trying to make a silverlight application that uses RIA Services for authentication and databinding.
That is, I'd like to be able to use the login/registration forms provided in the Business Application Template, and use the drag&drop features for displaying data in datagrid on pages.
The data for the application (including membership data) is stored in an existing SQL Server database.
So I am going to create a new membership provider class that inherits the MembershipProvider abstract class from the System.Web.Secruty namespace, to work with the existing database.
 1. Is this the right approach?
 2. How can you configure the AuthenticationService.cs in the business Application Template to work with the newly created custom membership provider class?
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to configure your membership provider in web.config.  The purpose of the provider model is to make implementations interchangeable.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx